# ASP.Net Error in inserting Data To OleDb

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I keep getting this error. I read that OleDb doesn't support named parameters so I changed them to `(?, ?)`.

But is keep getting the same error

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in INSERT INTO
>   statement. at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult
>   hr) at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS
>   dbParams, Object& executeResult) at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object&
>   executeResult) at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, Object& executeResult) at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method) at
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at
>   Registration.ImageButton1_Click(Object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
>   in c:\Users\Nirre\Desktop\Cti Project\Book Club TRY
>   2\Registration.aspx.cs:line 51

Here is the code in the .cs class

```
 protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string insCmd = @"INSERT COUNT(*) INTO Registration(UserName, [Password], EmailAddress, FullName, Country, PasswordRecovery)
                     VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        OleDbCommand insertUser = new OleDbCommand(insCmd, conn);
        insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", txtUserName.Text);
        insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassoword.Text);
        insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", txtEmail.Text);
        insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", txtFullName);
        insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", DdlCountry.SelectedItem.ToString());
        insertUser.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PasswordRecovery", txtAnswer.Text);

        try
        {
            insertUser.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            Response.Write(er);
            lblError.Visible = true;
            lblError.Text = "An error has ocured pleas try again...!";
        }
        finally
        {
            // Code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Plain-text passwords make me sad :( Also... why was this ancient question at the top of the list again?

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT COUNT(*)` is not a valid SQL statement, simply remove `COUNT(*)` and the rest of your code seems correct.

[See here for refs](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

Comment: This is a little strange: Do you mean `txtFullName.Text` instead of  `txtFullName`?

Comment: Thanx Steve, lol it was missing the .Text over looked it think i have been working to long now need a break and some sleep

Answer (score 1):

```
string insCmd = @"INSERT COUNT(*) INTO Registration(UserName, [Password], EmailAddress, FullName, Country, PasswordRecovery)
                     VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Should be

```
string insCmd = @"INSERT INTO Registration(UserName, [Password], EmailAddress, FullName, Country, PasswordRecovery)
                     VALUES (@UserName, @Password, @EmailAddress, @FullName, @Country, @PasswordRecovery)";
```

I don't understand what did you want to do with COUNT. If you want to then return number of affected rows, just add return parameter and assign @@ROWCOUNT to it

Edit: I've never used question marks as parameter placeholders outside Reporting Services so try replacing them with named parameters as shown above.

Comment: Yeah soz my bad over looked it "Whoops" but still get the same error

Comment: You need `?` rather than named placeholders for the `OleDb` provider.